# Cookie delete function stops working after ajax complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cookies

When the page loads, a cookie is created via PHP prior to any other content or headers with this code:

```
$steam_login_verify = SteamSignIn::validate();
if(isset($_COOKIE['userid']))
{
     //work with cookie value to get data;
     $steam_login_verify = $_COOKIE['userid'];

     $id = new SteamId($steam_login_verify);

     $name = $id->getNickname(); 
     $baseUrl = $id->getBaseUrl();
     $medAvatar = $id->getMediumAvatarUrl();
} else if(!empty($steam_login_verify))
{
     //create the cookie and store the user id as the value
     $exDate = time()+60*60*24*365;
     setcookie('userid', $steam_login_verify, $exDate,'/');

     $id = new SteamId($steam_login_verify);
     $name = $id->getNickname(); 
     $baseUrl = $id->getBaseUrl();
     $medAvatar = $id->getMediumAvatarUrl();
}
```

I am then using [James Auldridge's cookies plugin](http://code.google.com/p/cookies/) for jQuery to manage the cookie.

Once the user logs in via Stream, their Steam64Id is stored in the cookie for a year to keep them from having to log in every time they visit they page (assuming they will visit it on a regular basis).

I then  use the Steam64Id in an ajax call to get all of the users friends and populate a select element with their names.

On the page is a "Logout" button that, when clicked, will delete the cookie and refresh the page, causing the user to have to login via Steam again. This is where I am having the issue.

As long as the ajax call is running (and it takes a while to run ~57 sec) the logout button works just fine. Once that call is complete and the select element is populated, the logout button fails with an error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'del' of undefined
```

The code that this error refers to is the function that deletes the cookie and refreshes the page:

```
$('#logout').click(function() {
     $.cookies.del('userid');
     window.location.reload();
});
```

I do not understand the error, or why it is being thrown. Any help here would be great.

Comment: What that is saying is that `$.cookies` is `undefined` -- in other words, jQuery is not available at that moment for some reason.  We need to see more of your JS code -- the PHP is irrelevant to the error (right now).  Can you post the JS?

Comment: **57 seconds** holy cow.  The error means that there's no "cookies" property anymore.

Comment: @Pointy but don't forget premature optimization is the root of all evil.  I'm more worried about the lack of the `cookies` object on the jQuery object than the timing for him. Test servers are usually slow :)

Comment: Well yes I agree but in this day and age fixing something that takes almost a minute is hardly "premature optimization". Web services really need sub-second response times; humans just won't wait that long.

Comment: I would have to see more client side code and the AJAX response to be sure, but I suspect that the AJAX response includes a SCRIPT tag which reloads jQuery, causing all loaded plugins (cookies library included) to be deleted. Remember that `$.cookies` is an alias to `jaaulde.utils.cookies` so part of your troubleshooting could be to use that instead and see if it works then.

Comment: @JAAulde - Yes, there is a script tag in the AJAX page that controls the functionality of the select element. I will see about moving this and hopefully that will fix the issue. EDIT - Yup, that did it! Thank you sir.

Comment: @Pointy - There is not much I can do about the load time as it is dependent on Steam and the number of friends a person has on their friends list. I know, i wish it wasn't so long myself.

Comment: @AverageJoe cool, I am copying my comment to an answer, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have to see more client side code and the AJAX response to be sure, but I suspect that the AJAX response includes a SCRIPT tag which reloads jQuery, causing all loaded plugins (`$.cookies` reference included) to be deleted.

Remember that `$.cookies` is an alias to `jaaulde.utils.cookies` so part of your troubleshooting could be to use that instead and see if it works then.